# What's the best way to start Svelte app on production server?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit

I'm using SvelteKit (1.0.0) with the node adapter.

I want to use it on my server and start it with `pm2`.

What's the best way of starting a Svelte app with a node adapter without `npm start`?

I don't need pm2 command, just an npm command for Svelte.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
node build/index.js  # Start production server
```

Full example:

```
npm init svelte@next # Initialize project
npm install          # Install dependencies
npm run build        # Build production version
node build/index.js  # Start production server
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting 2 rows when I run `pm2 start node build/index.js --name Example`.  Am I doing something wrong? What script do you recommend?

Comment: @Ulvi: Sorry, I'm not familiar with `pm2` and I don't know what "2 rows" means.

Comment: Thank you @Leftium! As a JS/Svelte/SvelteKit-beginner I was always wondering, what *"serving your app"* after running `npm run build` meant. Your post has shed a lot of light into my head :-).

Comment: @Ulvi for next runs you just need to type `pm2 start Example` but before that you need to remove your previously duplicates by `pm2 remove Example`.